RedisCluster client failing to reconnect to AWS Elasticache cluster after node failover
lib - redis py redis==5.0.0
python version 3.7
redis cluster - 1 shard, 2 nodes
when we do node failovers, the client cannot reconnect and throw RedisClusterException:Redis Cluster cannot be connected. Please provide at least one reachable node: <None, or some IP, Timeout connecting to server>.
creating redis cluster connection like this -
client = redis.cluster.RedisCluster.from_url(url, read_from_replicas=True)
Then using this client as a singleton object across application.
want the client to know when a failover happens about updated node information. how to do this properly?
